# Are there any full featured Brainfuck editors available?

Tags: editor, brainfuck

Has anyone tried to implement the equivalent of a full featured editor for Brainfuck? What's the closest that is available?

Comment: What features would such an editor include? Source code highlighting (trivial to write a regex for)? Code folding (because that makes glossing over the general structure so much easier)? Perhaps even in-depth static analysis? ;)

Comment: Autocomplete? Search-and-replace? Refactoring tools? I originally thought of this question as a fun thought exercise, but it seems like a worthwhile one to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brainfuck Developer](http://4mhz.de/bfdev.html) is an IDE for the Brainfuck language.

Answer (score 3):

In 2008 I implemented a editor/debugger/interpreter for Brainfuck in JavaScript.
It's browser based, so you don't have to install anything.

You can put breakpoints and run brainfuck step by step.
There are also several examples included.

It's http://www.lordalcol.com/brainfuckjs/

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Brainfu** machine](http://www.kacper.kwapisz.eu/index.php?i=19), I use it for years, and it seems really good.